# Make resizeable JTable's columns' width resistant to structure change

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I have resizeable `JTable` in my application, some resize only cols, only row or both. To do so, I modify the `TableModel` and execute the `structureDataChanged()` method on it.

The problem is that my columns not conserve them width and always goes wider.

### Already tested :

- Adding a `Component` listener and listening changes :

  ```
  this.getTableHeader().addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
          super.componentResized(e);
          displayColumnWidths(getTableHeader());
      }

      private void displayColumnWidths(JTableHeader header) {
          TableColumnModel model = header.getColumnModel();
          for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
              TableColumn column = model.getColumn(i);
              column.setMaxWidth(50);
          }
      }
  });
  ```
- Overriding `doLayout()` method :

  ```
  @Override
  public void run() {

      final TableColumnModel columnModel = this.getColumnModel();

      int width = 50;
      for (int column = 0; column < this.getColumnCount(); column++) {

          TableCellRenderer renderer = this.getCellRenderer(0, column);
          Component comp = this.prepareRenderer(renderer, 0, column);
         if(comp == null)
              continue;
          width = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width + 1, width);
          columnModel.getColumn(column).setMaxWidth(width);
      }
      super.doLayout();
  }
  ```
- And as I began to lose I hope also tried both.
- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256219/jtable-column-width) may seems to have valuable solution. But I still want to know **why the others methods don't work**.

### Results

The result are the same : the column dimensioning is working on initialization until a `fireStructureChange()` event.

Some of the arrays are well dimensioned at random time as I resize my `JTable` but its still random and often delayed in time.

### Extra informations

I use this class (simply a `JTable`) and make all my resizeable array inherit from it :

```
public Resizeable(AbstractTableModel m) {
        super(m);
        this.setRowMargin(0);
        this.setShowGrid(false);
        this.setBackground(ViewsPreferences.P_TABLE_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        this.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        this.setBorder(null);
        this.setIntercellSpacing(new Dimension(0,0));
        this.changeSelection(0, 0, false, false);
        this.getTableHeader().setBackground(ViewsPreferences.PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        this.setAutoResizeMode(AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        this.setFillsViewportHeight(false);
}
```

Comment: `structureChanged` may not be the most appropriate event, as this causes the table to rebuild it's `TableColumnModel` on the assumption that the old one is no longer valid

Comment: Thanks. And what do you suggest ? `fireDataChanged()` has no effects. And if it redraws all the `JTable` why the first methods doesn't work ? (this is my initial question).

Comment: `And what do you suggest ? fireDataChanged() has no effects.` - that is what I would suggest, but we have no ideas how you are actually changing the data in your TableModel. Why are you using a custom TableModel? What is wrong with the DefaultTableModel. Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problems, if you need more help.